# jQuery validation with ajax not working proberly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my php code, I use a form which asks for an url.

My Problem is, the first validation to check if the input is empty or not, works fine.

The second validation *'URL is valid / reachable or not'* gives me the alert, if the URL is not valid. But it also submits the form. I cannot find the issue. Thank you for your help.

**form with input and a onSubmit="return validate();"**

```
<input class="form-control url" id="url" name="formVar" type="text">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
      check website
     </button> 
   </span>
```

**validation**

```
function validate() {

    var f = document.seocheck;

    var valid = true;

    alert(f.url.value);

    if (f.url.value == "") {
        alert('Pls insert an url');
        valid = false;

    }

    if (f.url.value != "") {

        jQuery.ajax({
            url : jQuery(f.url.value).val(),
            success : function(data, textStatus) {
                valid = true;
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Pls check the url');
                valid = false;
            }
        });

    }
    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your valid is initiated as true.

Because ajax is async it will not wait for your jquery ajax to return a result so will regardless return true which is what valid what set to.

Using ajax there is no simple way to have a validation function to  return true or false. 
I would recommend you changing your code so if valid, call a function that will submit.

Depending on your version of jquery you can change async to false, but this is deprecated in new versions of jquery (as of 1.8) and is not recommended.

Try something like this:

```
function validate() {

    var f = document.seocheck;

    alert(f.url.value);

    if (f.url.value == "") {
        alert('Pls insert an url');
        return false;

    }

    if (f.url.value != "") {

        jQuery.ajax({
            url : jQuery(f.url.value).val(),
            success : function(data, textStatus) {
                $('.btn btn-default').trigger('submit', [true]);
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Pls check the url');
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Also consider forcing crossDomain to true in the ajax call, although it should be true by default for cross domain.

Comment: @user2338488: I´ve tried your code, thank you. The validation works perfektly. But the alert ('Pls check the url') do not appear. I use jQuery 1.11.0